# Multiple pins within a function argument

Tags: c, arduino

Hello Stackoverflow users!

It's the line trafiksignal(redLed && yellowLed, 1000); I can't get to work, I'm trying to create a trafic signal using a function, and my idea was to use this picture as a guide: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f8/Traffic_lights_4_states.png/220px-Traffic_lights_4_states.png
(can't post pictures due to rep < 10)

My code: http://pastebin.com/MTGsYeXs

---

```
/* 
* @Author: Kristian Nymann
* @Date:   2014-09-25 22:46:39
* @Last Modified by:   Kristian Nymann
* @Last Modified time: 2014-09-25 23:23:19
* @Description: Lav et program der får de tre lysdioder til at skifte som et trafiklys. Du kan brugeprogrammet "Blink" som eksempel.
*/

const byte greenLed = 2;
const byte yellowLed = 3;
const byte redLed = 4;

void setup() {
pinMode(greenLed, OUTPUT);
pinMode(yellowLed, OUTPUT);
pinMode(redLed, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    trafiksignal(redLed, 3000);
    trafiksignal(redLed && yellowLed, 1000);
    trafiksignal(greenLed, 3000);
    trafiksignal(yellowLed, 1000);
}

void trafiksignal(byte pin, unsigned int duration)
{
    digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
    delay(duration);
    digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
}
```

Right now what's going on is:
Red led turns on for 3 sec.. then green led turns on for 3 sec, then yellow turns on for 1 sec..

So how can I make the yellow and red Led turn on at the same time? (why doesn't trafiksignal(redLed && yellowLed, 1000); work?)

Comment: Having <10 rep doesn't stop you from putting your code into the question here, or explaning HOW your code doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to this.. I think I have edited the OP to contain what is missing :-)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware && in C is for logical comparison only.

```
trafiksignal(redLed && yellowLed, 1000);
```

What this line is basically doing is checking if redLed and yellowLed are true or false, and if they're both true it will send a 1 or if either are false it will send a 0. Since both of them are not 0 it should treat them as both true so you're actually most likely telling pin 1 to go high for 1 second instead of pin 3 and 4.

A few simple work around would be to either create a separate function for turning the red and yellow light off or putting a quick if clause inside trafiksignal functio. Bellow is a quick a dirty if statement to add to trafiksignal that should get you up and running with your current code.

```
if (pin == 1) {
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
  delay(duration)
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
 }
else {
  digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
  delay(duration);
  digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
}
```

Typed the code from my ipad so I would proof read it before copy and pasting.

edited from my computer:

A better solution would be to send the pins to the function as an array, i'm not super experienced in plain C so I'm not sure if what i've done bellow is 100% accurate but it should be fairly close.

```
const byte greenLed = 2;
const byte yellowLed = 3;
const byte redLed = 4;
const byte redYellow[2] = {redLed, yellowLed} // create an array of 2 pins


void setup() {
pinMode(greenLed, OUTPUT);
pinMode(yellowLed, OUTPUT);
pinMode(redLed, OUTPUT);
}

    void loop() {
    // the middle number is the number of LEDs the function will need to control.
        trafiksignal(redLed, 1, 3000);
        trafiksignal(redYellow, 2, 1000);
        trafiksignal(greenLed, 1, 3000);
        trafiksignal(yellowLed, 1, 1000);
    }

    void trafiksignal(byte pin[], unsigned int numberOfLeds, unsigned int duration)
    {
      for (int i =0; i < numberOfLeds; ++i {
        digitalWrite(pin[i], HIGH);
      }
        delay(duration);
       for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLeds; ++i) {
        digitalWrite(pin[i], LOW);
       }
    }
```